# @Inject a @Remote EJB in Web Application

Tags: java, cdi, ejb-3.2

Is it possibile to `@Inject` a `@Remote` EJB in a Web Application?
I'm running on Glassfish 5 and I'm deploying an EAR (EJB + WAR).

When I annotate the EJB interface with `@Local` CDI works, with `@Remote` not.
What might be the cause?

By the way, using `@EJB` instead of `@Inject` works flawlessly, but I'm up to solve the `@Inject` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDI is not able to resolve remote ejb beans. As per the specs `3.2.2`

> The unrestricted set of bean types for a session bean contains all
>   local interfaces of the bean and their superinterfaces. If the session
>   bean has a no-interface view, the unrestricted set of bean Declaring a
>   session bean 41 types contains the bean class and all superclasses. In
>   addition, java.lang.Object is a bean type of every session bean.
>   Remote interfaces are not included in the set of bean types.

What you can do is to have a field producer for the remote interfaces, if you must use CDI injections rather than `@EJB`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll let the container manage dependencies and I'll stick with @EJB.